# What is the purpose of biasing op amp inputs in this Spice model?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

This is a two stage amplifier, the first is a high gain charge-sensitive pre-amplifier (U1) followed by a low gain voltage amplifier (U2). A typical charge-sensitive pre-amp for photodiodes has the non-inverting input grounded, whereas this model has it biased slightly (U1). U2 also has its inverting input biased. What is the purpose of this? Is it simply to make the model more realistic?

This is a pre-amp designed for a radiation detector biased around 1000 V. The detector would be AC-coupled to the pre-amp input.
Here are the details of the op amp from Spice (U1=U2):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you seen how the power supplies for the op-amps are connected? Either this is a very specialist design (which requires much more information) or it was designed by an unskilled bodger. Either way, maybe you can provide the details.

Comment: @Andyaka Are you referring to the transistors and diodes? I believe those are used in order to have a input supply voltage range +/-6V to +/-12V while keeping the opamp supply pins around +/-4V

Comment: Why no decoupling caps on the op-amps? Please provide op-amp details.

Comment: @Andyaka I am not sure why there are no decoupling caps. I've added details to the post.

Comment: @Andyaka It appears that the opamps are LTspice's *UniversalOpAmp2* which is a behavioral model. The power supplies only provide an output clipping threshold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason (related to the purpose of this circuit) they want to force the input to -0.15V. V4 is to make the output about 0V with the input at -0.15V.

If I was to take a wild guess, I'd say the input is something like a neutron detector and the bias increases the sensitivity, but only you know the purpose.

Comment: This is indeed a preamp for a radiation detector which are typically biased 1000V.

Comment: Maybe an attempt to compensate for leakage somewhere ahead of the input but seems unlikely to be very stable in practice.

Comment: The leakage currents with these detectors are typically in the nA range.

Comment: @earl 150mV/100MΩ = 1.5nA.

Comment: Well that doesn't seem like a coincidence! Thanks for the answer.